# Rails 6 - How to refer to javascript file variable in js.erb file?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar, erb, fullcalendar-5

I have a javascript calendar (FullCalendar v5) up and running in my Rails 6 app and everything works fine except my js.erb files. For example, when deleting a calendar event, the event is correctly deleted from the database and Rails goes correctly to my destroy.js.erb file. But my js.erb file does not recognize the calendar with the code

```
var calendar = document.getElementById('calendar');
var event = calendar.getEventById(<%= @calendar_event.id %>);
event.remove();
```

as I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: calendar.getEventById is not a function

(getEventById should be correct here https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEventById)

How can I correctly refer to the calendar from calendar.js in destroy.js.erb so that I can use the methods related to the FullCalendar library in the js.erb file?

Here is my current code related to this error:

calendar.js

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
        selectable: true,
        editable: true,

        events: "/calendar_events.json",

    eventClick: function (info) {
        $.getScript(info.event.extendedProps.edit_url, function () { });
    },

    });

    calendar.render();
});
```

destroy.js.erb:

```
var calendar = document.getElementById('calendar');
var event = calendar.getEventById(<%= @calendar_event.id %>);
event.remove();
```

index.html.erb

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

I am totally beginner in Javascript and been stuck in this for a while, so any help would be appreciated! :)

---

What I tried so far: I removed the `var calendar = document.getElementById('calendar');` from the destroy.js.erb file as suggested, but unfortunately the error was not solved, so then added `console.log(calendar)` to destroy.js.erb to see what "calendar" was referring to. What I got was the `<div id="calendar"></div>` element from index.html.erb. So

```
//destroy.js.erb
var event = calendar.getEventById(<%= @calendar_event.id %>);
event.remove();
```

"calendar" is currently referring to the div and not the calendar object from calendar.js. I also tried to rename `calendar` to `fullcalendar` in calendar.js to distinguish between the div and the calendar, but now I am getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: fullcalendar is not defined".

Comment: I am not sure about the solution but `document.getElementById('calendar')` will not return `Calendar` object probably which is the problem. `getEventById` is a valid function but on `Calendar` object. So if you could figure out a way for that it might fix the issue. Or if you can use the remove callback that should also fix: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRemove

Comment: @DeepeshKakani Yes, that is exactly the problem as the js.erb file does not recognize the Calendar object from calendar.js and I don't know how to correctly refer to it. Thus I cannot use the functions from the FullCalendar library in the js.erb file. My wording about the problem might have been unclear, I apologize for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var calendar = new Calendar ..` already defined (in `calendar.js`)and it's `Calendar`.
so if you re-define `var calendar = document.getElementById('calendar');` in `destroy.js.erb`, the variable `calendar` is not `Calendar` anymore.

so 1. make sure `calendar.js` is imported.

and 2. remove re-define calendar

```js
// destroy.js.erb
var event = calendar.getEventById(<%= @calendar_event.id %>);
event.remove();
```

note that it's better to define calendar as constant

```js
const calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, { ...`
```

then any `.js.erb` files attempt to re-define calendar will show the error `redeclaration`  and that's good since we get failed-fast.

Comment: I followed your instructions and removed the re-define calendar part, but I still get the same error of "Uncaught TypeError: calendar.getEventById is not a function". So I guess that the object "calendar" is still not correctly know to the js.erb file. About "make sure calendar.js is imported", is it enough that the file is required in the application.js file as "require("calendar")"? Should it be imported elsewhere?

Comment: sorry, my bad, in my project i defined variable also in .js.erb. Anyway, in your case, you can define `window.calendar = new Calendar(...` in `calendar.js` and access `window.calendar` in all `.js.erb`